# Android Certificate Store Protection?

Tags: android, security, certificate

We are using Android 4.0.4 ICS in an enterprise context, and i am trying to understand how Android protects the Key Store, specifically the Certificates Private Key.

What Hashing Algorithm does it use?

Are there any good reference materials out there that i can present to my Security Architect?

Comment: What key are you talking about? The one used to sign your apk?

Comment: No the main CA Certs stored in the android Key store, the ones you import via settings - e.g. For use with VPN connections.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Nikolay Elenkov's articles on ICS KeyChain if you want to see how that API is implemented inside. There are three articles in the series, but the article on [ICS Credential Storage Implementation](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/11/ics-credential-storage-implementation.html) tells you how the files are stored on disk.

Answer (score 0):

`keytool` is a standard Java tool for managing a keystore and associated X.509 certificates.
See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html) for more information; more specifically the section on supported algorithms:

> The default key pair generation algorithm is "DSA". The signature
>   algorithm is derived from the algorithm of the underlying private key:
>   If the underlying private key is of type "DSA", the default signature
>   algorithm is "SHA1withDSA", and if the underlying private key is of
>   type "RSA", the default signature algorithm is "MD5withRSA". When
>   generating a DSA key pair, the key size must be in the range from 512
>   to 1024 bits, and must be a multiple of 64. The default key size for
>   any algorithm is 1024 bits.

Comment: Is this what Android Uses for its KeyStore?

Comment: Yes this is what Android uses for creating and managing certificates.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#cert - "To generate a self-signed key with Keytool, use the keytool command"

Comment: That's for signing applications from a developer context. In the operation of the actual OS, the mechanisms used are described by the articles I linked to above.